# Use of Everyone with Who

Tags: verbs

> We thank everyone who **have** donated, helped set up, etc.

Is "have" correct or "has"?

Answer (score 2):

**"We thank *everyone who has* donated"** is correct. This is called *subject-verb agreement*.

The subject ("everyone") is singular, and "who" reflects the subject's number. Therefore the auxiliary verb "has" in the relative clause must be singular too.

> Words such as *either*, *neither*, ***everyone***, *everybody*, *anyone*, *anybody*, *someone*, *none* or *each*, are **singular** and need a **singular** **verb**.
>
> As we just said, don’t be fooled if a singular subject is followed by plural nouns. For example, when you write “each of my daughters,” make sure the verb agrees with the singular subject each instead of the plural noun daughters.
>
> And the singular subject “**everyone who knows** my daughters” should be followed by the singular predicate “is impressed by them,” not “are impressed by them.”

([www.dailywritingtips.com](http://www.dailywritingtips.com/six-rules-for-making-subjects-and-verbs-agree/))

Comment: _Who_ reflects the intrinsic number of its antecedent, which governs verb agreement in the relative clause. Quantifiers vary in their intrinsic grammatical number; _all_ and _any_ are plural --  _We thank all who have donated_, and _We thank any who have donated._

Comment: Thank you, John. I've edited the answer to include some of your valuable input.

Comment: In my experience, UK English speakers are more likely to use a noun as a group, non-singular, entity. For example, "The _engineering department_ **have** modified the source code for the firmware to fix the reported bug." In the USA, we're much more likely to use the singular verb in such an instance.